# cakephp code to pginate data using cakephp 1.3

Tags: cakephp

i am using cakephp 1.3 version.

i try to display data with pagination.but my code getting wrong query.

plz help to correct them.

below is my code...

```
 $this->paginate = array(
            'fields' => array('u_data.lane_id AS LaneId'),
            'joins' => array(array(
                                'table' => 'countries',
                                'alias' => 'origin_country',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array('origin_country.id'=>'CustomerRoute.origin_country')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'table' => 'countries',
                                'alias' => 'dest_country',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array('dest_country.id'=>'CustomerRoute.dest_country')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'table' => 'states',
                                'alias' => 'origin_state',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array('origin_state.id'=>'CustomerRoute.origin_state')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'table' => 'states',
                                'alias' => 'dest_state',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array('dest_state.id'=>'CustomerRoute.dest_state')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'table' => 'postalcodes',
                                'alias' => 'origin_city',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array('origin_city.id'=>'CustomerRoute.origin_city')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'table' => 'postalcodes',
                                'alias' => 'dest_city',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array('dest_city.id'=>'CustomerRoute.dest_city')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'table' => 'portfolios',
                                'alias' => 'p',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array('p.id'=>'CustomerRoute.portfolio_id')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'table' => 'supplier_uquotes_data',
                                'alias' => 'u_data',
                                'type' => 'LEFT',
                                'conditions' => array('CustomerRoute.id'=>'u_data.lane_id')
                            )),
            'conditions' => array('CustomerRoute.portfolio_id' =>'"'.$_SESSION["portfolioid"].'"', 'u_data.supplier_id IN' => '"'.implode(',',$_SESSION['supplierid']).'"'),
            'group' => array('CustomerRoute.id'),
            'limit' => 10);
        $content = $this->paginate('CustomerRoute');

        print_r($content);   
        exit;
```

the above code getting below query.....

```
SELECT `u_data`.`lane_id` AS `LaneId` FROM `customers` AS `Customer` INNER JOIN countries AS `origin_country` ON (`origin_country`.`id` = 'CustomerRoute.origin_country') INNER JOIN countries AS `dest_country` ON (`dest_country`.`id` = 'CustomerRoute.dest_country') INNER JOIN states AS `origin_state` ON (`origin_state`.`id` = 'CustomerRoute.origin_state') INNER JOIN states AS `dest_state` ON (`dest_state`.`id` = 'CustomerRoute.dest_state') INNER JOIN postalcodes AS `origin_city` ON (`origin_city`.`id` = 'CustomerRoute.origin_city') INNER JOIN postalcodes AS `dest_city` ON (`dest_city`.`id` = 'CustomerRoute.dest_city') INNER JOIN portfolios AS `p` ON (`p`.`id` = 'CustomerRoute.portfolio_id') LEFT JOIN supplier_uquotes_data AS `u_data` ON (`CustomerRoute`.`id` = 'u_data.lane_id') LEFT JOIN `jobtitles` AS `Jobtitle` ON (`Customer`.`job_title` = `Jobtitle`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `countries` AS `Country` ON (`Customer`.`country` = `Country`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `states` AS `State` ON (`Customer`.`state` = `State`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `market_areas` AS `MarketArea` ON (`Customer`.`market_area` = `MarketArea`.`id`)  WHERE `CustomerRoute`.`portfolio_id` = '\"69\"' AND `u_data`.`supplier_id` IN '\"37\"'  GROUP BY `CustomerRoute`.`id`   LIMIT 10
```

but i need the result like below mentioned query....the below mentioned query is my correct query.......

plz suggest whats the problem in my code..

```
SELECT u_data.lane_id AS LaneId, 
            origin_city.pcode AS origin_pcode, 
            dest_city.pcode AS dest_pcode
        FROM customer_routes AS CustomerRoute
        INNER JOIN countries AS origin_country ON ( origin_country.id = CustomerRoute.origin_country )
        INNER JOIN countries AS dest_country ON ( dest_country.id = CustomerRoute.dest_country )
        INNER JOIN states AS origin_state ON ( origin_state.id = CustomerRoute.origin_state )
        INNER JOIN states AS dest_state ON ( dest_state.id = CustomerRoute.dest_state )
        INNER JOIN postalcodes AS origin_city ON ( origin_city.id = CustomerRoute.origin_city )
        INNER JOIN postalcodes AS dest_city ON ( dest_city.id = CustomerRoute.dest_city )
        INNER JOIN portfolios AS p ON ( p.id = CustomerRoute.portfolio_id )
        LEFT JOIN supplier_uquotes_data AS u_data ON ( CustomerRoute.id = u_data.lane_id AND u_data.mode = '".$mode."')
        WHERE CustomerRoute.portfolio_id = '".$_SESSION["portfolioid"]."' AND u_data.supplier_id
        IN (".implode(',',$_SESSION['supplierid']).") GROUP BY CustomerRoute.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define remaining fields also and pass the Model name like this :

```
$this->Prg->commonProcess('CustomerRoute');
```

This is your code

```
$this->Prg->commonProcess('CustomerRoute');
        $this->paginate = array(
            'fields' => array('u_data.lane_id AS LaneId','origin_city.pcode AS origin_pcode','dest_city.pcode AS dest_pcode'),
            'joins' => array(array(
                                'table' => 'countries',
                                'alias' => 'origin_country',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array('origin_country.id'=>'CustomerRoute.origin_country')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'table' => 'countries',
                                'alias' => 'dest_country',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array('dest_country.id'=>'CustomerRoute.dest_country')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'table' => 'states',
                                'alias' => 'origin_state',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array('origin_state.id'=>'CustomerRoute.origin_state')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'table' => 'states',
                                'alias' => 'dest_state',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array('dest_state.id'=>'CustomerRoute.dest_state')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'table' => 'postalcodes',
                                'alias' => 'origin_city',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array('origin_city.id'=>'CustomerRoute.origin_city')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'table' => 'postalcodes',
                                'alias' => 'dest_city',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array('dest_city.id'=>'CustomerRoute.dest_city')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'table' => 'portfolios',
                                'alias' => 'p',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array('p.id'=>'CustomerRoute.portfolio_id')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'table' => 'supplier_uquotes_data',
                                'alias' => 'u_data',
                                'type' => 'LEFT',
                                'conditions' => array('CustomerRoute.id'=>'u_data.lane_id')
                            )),
            'conditions' => array('CustomerRoute.portfolio_id' =>'"'.$_SESSION["portfolioid"].'"', 'u_data.supplier_id IN' => '"'.implode(',',$_SESSION['supplierid']).'"'),
            'group' => array('CustomerRoute.id'),
            'limit' => 10);
        $content = $this->paginate('CustomerRoute');
```

Comment: but this shows error............Fatal error: Call to a member function commonProcess() on a non-object in /app/controllers/customers_controller.php

Comment: Hi lucky,It seems you not include Search.Prg component in that controller.
Please include public $components = array( 'Search.Prg');
If you have not Search Plugin then please download it from this url https://github.com/CakeDC/search

Comment: fine thank you..its working......... but can you tell me......how to put and conditions inside this........line.... 'conditions' => array('CustomerRoute.id'=>'u_data.lane_id')   i need to pass below condtion in above line.........( CustomerRoute.id = u_data.lane_id AND u_data.mode = '".$mode."')

Comment: Yes you can pass like this
'conditions' => array('CustomerRoute.id  = u_data.lane_id AND u_data.mode = '".$mode."')')  
OR
Like this
'conditions' => array('CustomerRoute.id  = u_data.lane_id' , 'u_data.mode = '".$mode."')')